# this.lookupReference('referenceName') returning null?

Tags: extjs

I created a login page, for my project, I made it work, but the problem is, I can't call the reference of the login form from my login controller, what could possible go wrong? please see below for my code:

This is my Login.Js which is under classic -> src -> view -> login -> Login.js:

```
Ext.define('DevToolsTraining.view.login.Login', {
extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
 xtype: 'loginView',

 requires: [
   'DevToolsTraining.view.login.LoginController',
   'Ext.form.Panel'
 ],

 viewModel:{
     type: 'login',
     data:{
         username: ''
     }
 },
controller: 'login',

title: 'Enter Username',
frame: true,
width: 320,
bodyPadding: 10,
closable: false,
autoShow: true,

layout: 'form',

items: [
    {
        xtype: 'login',
        reference: 'loginForm',  //i'm trying to call this 
        defaultType: 'textfield',
        bind: '{Login}',
        items: [{
            id:'txtUsername',
            allowBlank: false,
            fieldLabel: 'Username',
            name: 'Username',
            emptyText: 'enter username here...',
            bind: '{username}'
        }],
        buttons: [{
                text: 'Proceed>>',
                formBind: true,
                handler: 'onProceedClick'
            }]
    }
]

});
```

And here is my controller under app -> view -> login -> LoginController.js

```
Ext.define('DevToolsTraining.view.login.LoginController', {
extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
alias: 'controller.login',


onProceedClick: function () {
    var form = this.lookupReference('loginForm'); //this returns null it's like it can't see the "loginForm" reference
    var username = Ext.getCmp('txtUsername').getValue(); //i got the value of the textbox here but i don't like this coz what if I have more textFields

    if (username != '')
    {
        Ext.Ajax.request({
                url: '/api/Users/Post',
                method: 'POST',
                params: username,
                scope: this,
                success: function (form, response) {

                    localStorage.setItem("username", username);

                    this.getView().destroy();

                    Ext.create({
                        xtype: 'app-main'
                    });
                },
                failure: function(form, response){
                    Ext.MessageBox.alert("Test");
                }
            })
    }
    else {
        Ext.MessageBox.alert("Error", "Please enter username to view contacts");
    }
},
/**
 * Called when the view is created
 */
init: function () {

}
});
```

Comment: Can you please create a sample fiddle for this so as to solve the issue there?

Comment: nvm, I got it working, I used this.view.viewModel.data instead

Comment: in that case you can use this.view.getForm() also

Comment: actually it didn't work that's why I was really puzzled

Comment: i believe it needs xtype as form but u have used layout as form instead. i mean its a form only in your case but for that this.view.getForm() to work you need to specify that as xtype

Comment: Your code leaves out a lot of detail, but here is a similar fiddle that shows the reference is retrievable: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/24ia

Comment: hi Evan can we have a chat? I have a lot of questions to ask regarding ExtJs